# Azure ARM template - derive Automation Account registration Url and Key at runtime

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager

I'm trying to derive the Registration Key and Url of my Azure Automation DSC account inside the ARM template at runtime. I've tried using the same syntax as you would for a storage account, ie.

```
listKeys(resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', 'StorageAccountName'), '2015-05-01-preview').key1)
```

by doing this:

```
listKeys(resourceId('Microsoft.Automation/automationAccounts', 'AutomationAccountName'), '2015-05-01-preview').key1)
```

but no luck (it appears the function simply returns null). This would naturally make provisioning an automation account and and a VM and wiring up the VM to the automation account in the same template easy as pie. Has anyone successfully got something similar to work?

Answer (score 1):

As per this GitHub Ticket, this is still under development.

https://github.com/azureautomation/automation-packs/issues/7

Answer (score 1):

With version `2015-10-31` of the Azure Automation API, the following seems to work.

Getting the registration URL:

```
reference(resourceId('Microsoft.Automation/automationAccounts/', 'AutomationAccountName'), '2015-10-31').RegistrationUrl
```

Getting the Primary key:

```
listKeys(resourceId('Microsoft.Automation/automationAccounts/', 'AutomationAccountName'), '2015-10-31').keys[0].value
```

Getting the Secondary key:

```
listKeys(resourceId('Microsoft.Automation/automationAccounts/', 'AutomationAccountName'), '2015-10-31').keys[1].value
```

---

For reference, the object returned from the `listKeys()` template function for an Automation account resource looks like this (can easily be found by adding an output value using `listKeys()` to the outputs section of an ARM template):

```
{
  "keys": [
    {
      "KeyName": "Primary",
      "Permissions": "Full",
      "Value": "VALUE OF PRIMARY KEY"
    },
    {
      "KeyName": "Secondary",
      "Permissions": "Full",
      "Value": "VALUE OF SECONDARY KEY"
    }
  ]
}
```